# Avoiding public method decorators in a Swift public class extension

Tags: swift, interop, protocols, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

Suppose I defined a protocol in Swift:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  func myMethod() -> String
}
```

I then define a class in the same source file:

```
public class MyClass: NSObject {
  var myVariable = ""
  func myOtherMethod()
}
```

I then add an extension to `MyClass` specifying a conformance to `MyProtocol` in the same source file:

```
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
  func myMethod() -> String {
    return "abc"
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the above code in Xcode 7.2, I get a compiler error telling me that I need to add a public decorator to each of the extension's methods:

```
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
  public func myMethod() -> String {
    return "abc"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid annotating every method in a class extension like the above with `public`?

Note: I know that removing `public` from `MyClass` makes the above compile error go away but I need `MyClass` to be visible to Objective-C code that uses it.